# How to check if a string/variable begins with a mobile area code?

Tags: javascript

Tried various options, but not working. Javascript.

Need to recognise if a variable begins with "+614" as opposed to "+254", in an `if` statement.

Things I've tried

```
for(var i=0; i<views.length; i++){
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(inputString)) ) {
        data += views[i].pageviews;
    }
}
```

```
for(var i=0; i<views.length; i++){
    if (user_phone_number.startsWith("614")) {
        data += views[i].value;
    }
}
```

```
if (user_phone_number.substring(0,2) == "614"){newResult += 1;}
```

Thank you! I'm not very good at this!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Any problem with `.startsWith("+614")`? The truth value of your `if` in a loop is invariant and doesn't depend on the loop element so you should invert the loop and the `if`. JS uses `camelCase`, not `snake_case`. `substring(0, 2)` is non-inclusive of the right index, so comparing a two-character or less string against a three-character string is guaranteed to be false.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

**Try Using**

```js
var user_no = "+614-9978239084"

if(user_no.startsWith("+614")) {
 console.log(true);
}

if(user_no.substring(1,4) == "614") {
  console.log(true);
}
```